# Python ssl sockets TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I am coding a simple ssl secured client server echo message program. I am getting a client side type error --> an integer is required. Below is the code for the client

```
 import socket
import ssl

c_con = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_ip = '*******'
server_port = 4444
print('Connecting to %s port %d' % (server_ip,server_port))
c_con.connect((server_ip,server_port))

ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(c_con,ssl_version = "TLSv1")

try:
    message = raw_input('Enter your message --> ')
    print('Sending "%s"' % message)
    ssl_sock.sendall(message)

    #Echo part
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)

    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = ssl_sock.recv(1024)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print('Received "%s"' % data)

finally:
    print('Closing socket')
    ssl_sock.close()
```

Please help me out. I checked the related questions to the topic but couldn't figure out my solution.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual error with the full traceback. However, I assume the TypeError is raised when calling `ssl.wrap_socket(c_con,ssl_version = "TLSv1")`. The ssl_version parameter is expected to be an integer. Either pass  `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1` to that parameter or use the integer `3`.

Answer (score 1):

here is the probleme :

```
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(c_con,ssl_version = "TLSv1")
```

the tls version are not correct , you must do like that:

```
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(c_con,ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

don't make ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1 an str , its alerady defined

and check if you'r host can support TLSv1 protocol

Comment: I have tried using the same but it returns an error --> SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER .   I have also tried using other protocols  across client and server but same error.